# Reloading specific base files

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, fstab

I am using Arch Linux and I have cleared the `fstab` file on accident. 
Of course I regenerate the fstab with

```
genfstab -U -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

the thing is, I do not know what was in the beginning of the file and I know that using `>>` just adds to a file. So I am assuming that there might have been script before I screwed with the file.

In arch Linux we use something called pacstrap and I ran something like this

```
pacstrap -i /mnt base
```

so I image in the base packages there is a fstab file. Is this true? This made me think maybe I should know how to target specific packages or files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pacstrap` is part of [arch-install-scripts](https://projects.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/tree/pacstrap.in); you can read the script to understand how it works.

As the help message notes:

> pacstrap installs packages to the specified new root directory. If no packages
> are given, pacstrap defaults to the "base" group.

[pkgfile](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/pkgfile/) is a utility that lets you query pacman's database:

```
pkgfile /etc/fstab
core/filesystem
```

So, to create a new `/etc/fstab`, you could simply `pacstrap /mnt/filesystem` and deal with any `*.pac{new,save}` files. In your case, however, running `genfstab` (and then manually checking the result) would be sufficient.